# Python Alarm Clock

Tags: python, nonblocking

I've made this little alarm clock with a little help from my brother. I tried it last night, with out the `nonBlockingRawInput` and that worked fine, but with the `nonBlockingRawInput` it didn't work. Today I've tried it but neither of them work! I will post the code with the `nonBlockingRawInput` and the "non" file. If you want the code without `nonBlockingRawInput`, just ask.

Thanks in advance.

**alarm rpi.py**:

```
import time
import os
from non import nonBlockingRawInput

name = input("Enter your name.")

print("Hello, " + name)

alarm_HH = input("Enter the hour you want to wake up at")
alarm_MM = input("Enter the minute you want to wake up at")

print("You want to wake up at " + alarm_HH + ":" + alarm_MM)

while True:
    now = time.localtime()
    if now.tm_hour == int(alarm_HH) and now.tm_min == int(alarm_MM):
        print("ALARM NOW!")
        os.popen("open mpg321 /home/pi/voltage.mp3")
        break

    else:
        print("no alarm")
    timeout = 60 - now.tm_sec
    if nonBlockingRawInput('', timeout) == 'stop':
        break
```

**non.py**:

```
import signal

class AlarmException(Exception):
    pass

def alarmHandler(signum, frame):
    raise AlarmException

def nonBlockingRawInput(prompt='', timeout=20):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, alarmHandler)
    signal.alarm(timeout)
    try:
        text = input(prompt)
        signal.alarm(0)
        return text
    except AlarmException:
        pass
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal.SIG_IGN)
    return ''
```

Comment: you might want to give it a range of time so that it can trigger if it  the check doesn't perfectly hit the time

Comment: what about it is not working?

Comment: Well for starters, the music isn't playing. But for some reason last night it was? And also, the second code is what my brother made, and its so when the music is playing you type in stop so it stops, but that doesn't work either. Sorry if I'm jumbling my words up, I am quite new to Python.

Comment: Whats the error that the interpreter throws? This might be a simple indentation problem

Answer (score 7):

I've been looking at your code for a while now. As far as I can understand you want to be able to run an alarm while also being able to type "stop" in the shell to end the program, to this end you can make the alarm a thread. The thread will check if its time to say "ALARM!" and open the mp3. If the user hasn't typed stop in the shell, the thread will sleep and check again later.

I essentially used your code and just put it into an alarm thread class:

```
import time
import os
import threading


class Alarm(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, hours, minutes):
        super(Alarm, self).__init__()
        self.hours = int(hours)
        self.minutes = int(minutes)
        self.keep_running = True

    def run(self):
        try:
            while self.keep_running:
                now = time.localtime()
                if (now.tm_hour == self.hours and now.tm_min == self.minutes):
                    print("ALARM NOW!")
                    os.popen("voltage.mp3")
                    return
            time.sleep(60)
        except:
            return
    def just_die(self):
        self.keep_running = False



name = raw_input("Enter your name: ")

print("Hello, " + name)

alarm_HH = input("Enter the hour you want to wake up at: ")
alarm_MM = input("Enter the minute you want to wake up at: ")

print("You want to wake up at: {0:02}:{1:02}").format(alarm_HH, alarm_MM)


alarm = Alarm(alarm_HH, alarm_MM)
alarm.start()

try:
    while True:
         text = str(raw_input())
         if text == "stop":
            alarm.just_die()
            break
except:
    print("Yikes lets get out of here")
    alarm.just_die()
```

It is worth noting, that when the thread is sleeping, with:

```
time.sleep(60)
```

And you typed stop in the shell the thread would have to wake up before it realised it was dead, so you could at worst end up waiting a minute for the program to close!

Answer (score 1):

```
import winsound,time

a= int(input("Enter how many times I have beep  :"))
b= int(input("Enter when to wake up (in seconds) :"))

time.sleep(b)

for i in range(a):
    winsound.Beep(3000,100)
    winsound.Beep(2500,100)
    winsound.Beep(2000,100)    
    winsound.Beep(1000,100)    
    winsound.Beep(500,100)
```