# most efficient way to implement clock with alarm clock in Python

Tags: python, datetime, timer, clock, alarm

I am trying to implement a digital clock with alarm clock in Python. Now I am wondering what is the best way to implement the alarm clock functionality. I was able to find several similar projects, mostly concentrating on the alarm clock functionality. They just usually compute the time till the next wake up ad go to sleep for the computed amount of seconds.
See [here](http://pastebin.com/GLL6L2B8) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325039/python-alarm-clock):

My problem is, that I implement also a normal clock and display the time. For this reason I have to update the clock every second. In this loop I check if the alarm should not be set off. For this reason I am searching form easy and efficient implementation of the alarm clock functionality.

Inspired by the first example I ended up with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import datetime

class Clock:

    def __init__(self):

        # set the initial time
        self.hour = 0
        self.minute = 0
        self.second = 0
        # the update interval in seconds
        self.update_interval = 1
        self.keep_running = True
        # the instance of the alarm
        self.alarm = AlarmClock()

    def run(self):
        while self.keep_running:
            # update the clock time
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            self.hour = now.hour
            self.minute = now.minute
            self.second = now.second

            # now check if the alarm should not be started
            if self.alarm.is_active():
                if self.alarm.time_till_next_alarm() < 1:
                    # has to be done in separate thread
                    self.alarm.on_wake_up()

            time.sleep(self.update_interval)

    def get_alarm(self):
        return self.alarm


class AlarmClock:
    def __init__(self, hour=8, minute=0):
        # We start with predefined alarm at 8:00 which is not active
        self.hour = hour
        self.minute = minute
        self.active = False
        # the alarm should be stopped after some time (1h 00min)
        self.duration = datetime.timedelta(hours=1, minutes=0)

    def time_till_next_alarm(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()  # get current date & time

        # separate date and time from each other:
        currdate = datetime.date(now.year, now.month, now.day)
        currtime = datetime.time(now.hour, now.minute)
        alarmtime = self.get_wake_up_time()
        # add today's date onto the alarm time entered
        alarmdatetime = datetime.datetime.combine(currdate, alarmtime)
        if alarmtime <= currtime:  # if the alarm time is less than the current time set clock for tomorrow
            alarmdatetime += datetime.timedelta(hours=24)

        return alarmdatetime - now

    def set_time(self, hour, minute):
        self.hour = hour
        self.minute = minute

    def activate(self):
        self.active = True

    def deactivate(self):
        self.active = False

    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    def on_wake_up(self):
        # start the wake up
        print 'Wake up!'


#Execution starts here
if __name__ == '__main__':

    clock = Clock()
    clock.get_alarm().activate()
    clock.get_alarm().set_time(8,0)
    clock.run()
```

Is there any better or less computational demanding implementation ?

EDIT:

I would like to display the time on a 7-segment LCD display, [here are some details about the part.](http://bit.ly/1DQ6OXl) For this reason I write the digits on every update to the LCD display in the *run()* method

```
# set the tens and ones of hours and minutes
self.display.set_digit(0, int(self.hour / 10))     # Tens
self.display.set_digit(1, self.hour % 10)          # Ones
self.display.set_digit(2, int(self.minute / 10))   # Tens
self.display.set_digit(3, self.minute % 10)        # Ones
```

EDIT2:

Although the provided python library from Adafruit allows you to set the blink-rate for the whole display I would like to blink the colon at 1Hz frequency - to imply the rate of the seconds.

```
 # Toggle colon at 1Hz
 self.display.set_colon(self.second % 2)
```

Comment: I think a lot of this code could be removed but you don't show where you display the time so it's hard to guess some of the details. For instance, why keep `Clock.hour, Clock.minute, Clock.second` at all... its already in `datetime.datetime.now()`. As for the alarm, you could use threading.Timer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `sched` module. Included in Python standard library!

Docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html

Answer (score 1):

You could eliminate the AlarmClock class completely and just use `threading.Timer`. Most of the other class seems superfluous also - datetime objects already have hour, minute, second, so no need to keep your own version.

```
import datetime
import threading
import sys

def ring_ring():
    sys.stdout.write('ring ring\n')
    sys.stdout.flush()

class Clock:

    def __init__(self):
        self.alarm_time = None
        self._alarm_thread = None
        self.update_interval = 1
        self.event = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.event.wait(self.update_interval)
            if self.event.isSet():
                break
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            if self._alarm_thread and self._alarm_thread.is_alive():
                alarm_symbol = '+'
            else:
                alarm_symbol = ' '
            sys.stdout.write("\r%02d:%02d:%02d %s" 
                % (now.hour, now.minute, now.second, alarm_symbol))
            sys.stdout.flush()

    def set_alarm(self, hour, minute):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        alarm = now.replace(hour=int(hour), minute=int(minute))
        delta = int((alarm - now).total_seconds())
        if delta <= 0:
            alarm = alarm.replace(day=alarm.day + 1)
            delta = int((alarm - now).total_seconds())
        if self._alarm_thread:
            self._alarm_thread.cancel()
        self._alarm_thread = threading.Timer(delta, ring_ring)
        self._alarm_thread.daemon = True
        self._alarm_thread.start()

clock = Clock()
clock.set_alarm(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
clock.run()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You are probably about the redundancy of my class. I probably expressed myself vague with the time display. I connected an LED 7 segment display with i2c bus and I would like to display the current on it. I updated my first post with the related code. Some info about the display and provided libraries is to be find here: http://bit.ly/1DQ6OXl